# MySQL VIEW with IF statement

Tags: mysql, view, if-statement

i have two tables in mMySQL:

```
 - news (news_id, news_titel, news_file_id)
 - files (file_id, file_path, file_name)
```

I would like to create MySQL VIEW with these columns:

```
- news_view (news_id, news_title, news_file_id, news_file_path)
```

But, if `news_file_id > 0` then, i get the path of file (`file_path + file_name`) else `news_file_path` should be `0`

How can i do this VIEW?

EDIT

but what if i want to add two more tables :

```
categories (category_id, category_name)
users(user_id, user_name)
```

and table `news` changed to

```
news (news_id, news_title, news_file_id, news_author_id, news_category_id)
```

and view should show only posts with specifed `news_author_id`, `news_category_id`, but `news_file_path` like in the original question?

Thanks,
Paul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below:

```
 CREATE VIEW news_view  
   as (SELECT news_id, news_titel, news_file_id, 
       IF(news_file_id > 0, CONCAT(file_path, file_name), 0)
           AS news_file_path
       FROM news a LEFT JOIN files b
            ON a.news_file_id= b.file_id
         JOIN categories cat
            ON a.news_category_id = cat.category_id
         JOIN users u
            ON a.news_author_id = u.user_id
      );
```

Add the `where` condition as required.

Comment: What issue you got? There was an extra brace in my `if` statement, I removed that. Should be working fine.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that. There was an extra brace :( Typing mistake.

Comment: @user1763491  Oops, I notice you wanted `0`. I replaced that in the query. Looks like I typed the answer in little hurry.

Comment: You mean, if related records not present in `files`, its not showing up or even if the related records present, still not fetching?

Comment: IF `news_file_id` is `0`, the records should be in view with column `news_file_path` and value `0`. In your way if single post have `news_file_path = 0` then it isn't in the VIEW

Comment: I got it, in that case file is not there, correct?? If so, add `LEFT` in fron of join. I updated the answer. Also just curious, you have already accepted the answer. These issue were not there in that answer i.e. you got the records correctly?

Comment: Yep and yep. Am i wasting you time?

Comment: Not at all. Its a learning that no matter how good you know, if you make haste, it will result into errors. All above three issues were introduced just because of my hurry. Now the above query should also work. If so, please vote to acknowledge :)

Comment: I updated the answer with join condition. Do you mean you want to add some where clause e.g. where user_id ==.... and categroy_id =...? If yes, simply add them. There should not be any issue.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for providing valuable inputs to help.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, you can use `CASE` for your condition,

```
CREATE VIEW myView
AS
SELECT  a.news_id, a.news_title,
        a.news_file_id,
        CASE 
            WHEN news_file_id = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE CONCAT(file_path, file_name)
        END news_file_path
FROM    news a
        LEFT JOIN files b
            ON a.news_file_id = b.file_id
```

Comment: My master! :) Works very good. You forget about "AS", but rest of is very good. Thanks :)